# how to add mvc test project to upgraded web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I have an existing asp.net web application that I'm updating to include some MVC pages.  I have successfully upgraded the web app to recognize my MVC controllers/views/...  I can even get my test page to display correctly: hooray!

However, I am having trouble figuring out how to add a test project so that I can add my unit tests for the new pages.  Does anyone have a suggestion on how to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MSTest right click on the solution and `Add -> New Project...`. Select `Test Project` type. In the newly created project reference the project containing the controllers and start adding unit tests.

If you are using some 3rd party unit testing framework such as NUnit you could add a project of type `Class Library` and then add the unit tests to this class library.